# Is the ClCompile item a task as well?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I am trying to understand the visual cpp project document here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project).

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
  <ItemGroup>  
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">  
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>  
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>  
    </ProjectConfiguration>  
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">  
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>  
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>  
    </ProjectConfiguration>  
  </ItemGroup>  
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />  
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>  
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>  
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />  
  <ItemGroup>  
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />  
  </ItemGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>  
    <ClInclude Include="main.h" />  
  </ItemGroup>  
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />  
</Project>
```

I gather that ClCompile, is an item as it is nested under the ItemGroup tag, it also seems that the files to be compiled are referred to in the ClCompile tag. On the documentation page for Items, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items, it states that Items are inputs into the build system. I dont see a task above which takes these ClCompile items and compiles them, how is compilation being achieved? Is the ClCompile item as task as well?

Comment: It is a target, defined in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets.  Most relevant thing it does is execute the CL task.  The IDE pays attention to it as well, as it does to ClInclude, that is how it builds the project tree that visible in the Solution Explorer window.  You can lose several clumps of head hair figuring out how Microsoft.Cpp.Targets gets that ball rolling.

Comment: This might explain my hair loss.

Comment: Nicely explained in [MSBuild internals for C++ projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/msbuild-visual-cpp-overview):
*ClCompile*: _Executes the MSVC compiler tool, cl.exe._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont see a task above which takes these ClCompile items and compiles them, how is compilation being achieved? Is the ClCompile item as task as well?

After search all the `.targets` and `.props` files in the `VCTargets` folder under following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets
```

We could find following code snippet in the `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets` file:

```
 <Target Name="ClCompile"
          Condition="'@(ClCompile)' != ''"
          DependsOnTargets="SelectClCompile">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <CLToolArchitecture Condition="'$(CLToolArchitecture)' == ''">$(VCToolArchitecture)</CLToolArchitecture>
      <CLDeleteOutputOnExecute Condition="'$(CLDeleteOutputOnExecute)' == ''">true</CLDeleteOutputOnExecute>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ClNoDependencies Condition="'@(ClNoDependencies)' == '' and '%(ClInclude.NoDependency)' == 'true'" Include="@(ClInclude)"/>
      <ClNoDependencies Condition="'$(NoDependencies)' != ''" Include="$(NoDependencies)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    ...

    <OnError Condition="'$(OnXamlPreCompileErrorTarget)' != ''" ExecuteTargets="$(OnXamlPreCompileErrorTarget)" />
  </Target>
```

So `ClCompile` should be a target, which is used to execute the Visual C++ compiler tool, `cl.exe` to compile the C/C++ source file. That is reason why it not in the MSBuild-item.

See [MSBuild (Visual C++) Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662426.aspx) for some more details.

Comment: I think the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project) really ought to mention that ClCompile is a target, given that it is nested under ItemGroup makes it seem that it is an item

Comment: @aileronajay, yes, it should be. But this doc is used to talk about how to create a Visual C++ project via MSBuild, it could not explain something that is in-depth but rarely noticed. When some one noticed it, just like you. We will do our best to make you clear it. Of course, I will also try to suggest MS team to update this doc with your willing. If above answer resolved your doubt, you can accept it as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: It now mentions `CLCompile` as a target in the tutorial, might be elsewhere as well. Agreed, MS might consider listing this along with `CLInclude`, maybe others, in a special section in the [glossary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-glossary), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, CLCompile actually runs the CLTask task class. I suspect (though don't know for sure) they did it that way so they could have both CLCompile and CLInclude without having to write task implementations for each. I am not sure what namespace that is found in or the assembly, unlike tasks for pure .net languages the c++ tasks are not in the .net library docs.