# Always run Custom Build Event in Visual Studio (without VC++)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, custom-build-step

How can I **always** run a custom script in Visual Studio 2015, even if **nothing** has changed... but using VS **without** VS++ installed?

I effectively want to do the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937702/visual-studio-run-c-project-post-build-event-even-if-project-is-up-to-date) however, my installation of Visual Studio 2015 does **not** have VC++ installed (as everything we do is either C# or VB.Net) so I do not have access to the same project properties pages.

Using the accepted answer as a starting point, and [this article for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-add-a-custom-build-step-to-msbuild-projects?view=vs-2017) I have added the following to my project file, but I simply cannot get it to run the custom script unless a file in the project has changed...

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <CustomBuildStep>
      <Command>MyScript.vbs</Command>
      <Outputs>$(TargetName).missing</Outputs>
      <Inputs>$(TargetFileName)</Inputs>
    </CustomBuildStep>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>    
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <CustomBuildAfterTargets>ClCompile</CustomBuildAfterTargets>
  <CustomBuildBeforeTargets>Link</CustomBuildBeforeTargets>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have done a lot of searching for values for `<CustomBuildAfterTargets>` and `<CustomBuildBeforeTargets>` but I cannot find anything official or otherwise. It's highly frustrating for the MS article not to provide details on possible values.

I did also try adding the `<DisableFastUpToDateCheck>` attribute as per one of the answers, but that still rebuilds the project so isn't what I want.

Comment: Do you want to run this on a particular file, file type, or on the project as a whole?

Comment: @battlmonstr - The project as a whole.  Even if nothing has changed in any of the project files, I want a build to run the script

Comment: Have you tried defining this in UI? Like going to project settings, build steps and set your command there?

Comment: @battlmonstr - thanks for your comments.  I have repeatedly stated (including in the title) that I do not have VC++ installed, and therefore I don't get the same property pages.  So no, I haven't, because I don't have them... hence my question

Comment: @freefaller, are you building c# or c++?  ClCompile is a c++ compile target, not a c# compile target (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591809/is-the-clcompile-item-a-task-as-well).  I think you may be needing CoreCompile for c# (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667510/determine-if-msbuild-corecompile-will-run-and-call-custom-target?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @user9525052 - thanks for your response - I need C# and preferable VB.Net.  I'll investigate the links you've provided

Comment: Look at adding an Exec target to your project file.  Any halfway interesting customization in builds doesn't tend to fit all that well into the customization points that are supported in the project property pages, so you might end up with something that works better anyway.

Comment: Are you saying you don't have the "Build Events" tab on your project's property pages?  I have it on both C# and VB projects.

Comment: @Chris - no, I'm not saying that. I have "Build Events" (although not a tab, it's a button on the "Compile tab")... but it only provides pre-build and post-build events, both of which only fire when something has changed in the project

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem while trying to run a script that generated source code from a folder's contents.

I managed to trigger the Custom Action every time by adding a directory to the list of Inputs:

```
    <CustomBuildStep>
      <Outputs>all_templates.h</Outputs>
      <Inputs>Generate-TemplateFileHeader.ps1;$(ProjectDir)..\web\webadmin\</Inputs>
    </CustomBuildStep>
```

I *hoped* that the build system might detect changes to the directory and subsequently run the custom build step. It does not. Instead, it seems to *always* run the custom action.

Caveat:
I do not know if this is documented behavior. It could be purely accidental or based on my environment.